# how to add a button near a input form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentbootstrap

I'm using `fluentbootstrap` and i'm trying to add a button (with icon) near an input of my form.

Code :

```
using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().SetHorizontal().Begin())
{
    @form.InputFor(m => m.Id).SetReadonly().SetLg(3)
    @form.SelectFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.CountryList).SetLg(3)
    @form.InputFor(m => m.Name).SetLg(3)
    @Html.Bootstrap().Button().SetIcon(Icon.Film)
}
```

The result for the third row (with the field Name) is the control label + the input in the same row but the button is on the next row. I want my button in the same row of my input just after the input.

What is the solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, there is another solution :

```
    using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().SetHorizontal().Begin())
    {
        @form.InputFor(m => m.Id).SetReadonly().SetLg(3)
        @form.SelectFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.CountryList).SetLg(3)
        using (form.FormGroup(m => m.Name).SetMd(0).Begin())
        {
          @form.InputFor(m => m.Name).SetControlLabel(null).SetLg(3)
          @Html.Bootstrap().Button().SetIcon(Icon.Film)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This layout is a bit tricky - the key is to manually layout the last form group, including manually positioning the label:

```
using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().SetHorizontal().Begin())
{
    @form.InputFor(m => m.Id).SetReadonly().SetLg(3)
    @form.SelectFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.CountryList).SetLg(3)
    using (var formGroup = form.FormGroup().SetAutoColumns(false).Begin())
    {
        @form.ControlLabel(m => m.Name).SetMd(4)
        @form.InputFor(m => m.Name).SetControlLabel(null).SetLg(2)
        using (Html.Bootstrap().GridColumn().SetLg(1).Begin())
        {
            @Html.Bootstrap().Button().SetIcon(Icon.Film)
        }
    }
}
```